# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to run the code presented on the second page:

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/lecture-20/lec20.pdf

At the bottom of the code you have to add these lines:

```
simFlips(100,100)

show()
```

Here is the error that I get when I run it on ubuntu:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "coin.py", line 36, in <module>
    simFlips(100,100)
  File "coin.py", line 16, in simFlips
    diffs.append(abs(heads - tails))
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What am I doing wrong that gives me the last error?

Comment: For some reason your `diffs` variable is a numpy ndarray. Are you sure you left the line that says `diffs = []`? This sets diffs to be an empty python list, which you can call `append` on.

Comment: Works for me as written.

Comment: Yes I did, I just took the code from the pdf added the two lines at the bottom and started to get this error.

Comment: DSM, how did you execute the code.  On ubuntu or a different platform?

Answer (score 61):

Use `numpy.concatenate(list1 , list2)` or `numpy.append()`
Look into the thread at [Append a NumPy array to a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9775297/append-a-numpy-array-to-a-numpy-array).

Comment: Not to forget the `axis=0` or `axis=1` parameter in `np.concatenate()`.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, numpy arrays don't have have access to `append()`. If we look into documentation, we need to use `np.append(array)`, where `array` is the values to be appended.

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([1,2,3,47,1,0,2])

np.append(arr, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after change a loop in my program, let`s see:

```
for ...
  for ... 
     x_batch.append(one_hot(int_word, vocab_size))
     y_batch.append(one_hot(int_nb, vocab_size, value))
  ...
  ...
  if ...
        x_batch = np.asarray(x_batch)
        y_batch = np.asarray(y_batch)
...
```

In fact, I was reusing the variable and forgot to reset them inside the external loop, like the comment of John Lyon:

```
for ...
  x_batch = []
  y_batch = []
  for ... 
     x_batch.append(one_hot(int_word, vocab_size))
     y_batch.append(one_hot(int_nb, vocab_size, value))
  ...
  ...
  if ...
        x_batch = np.asarray(x_batch)
        y_batch = np.asarray(y_batch)
...
```

Then, check if you are using np.asarray() or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use numpy function to append numpy arrays. Append will workk only for ordinary lists not numpy arrays.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).