# numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'np'

Tags: python

```
for i in range(60,1259):
    X_train.append(training_scaled[i-60:i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_scaled[i,0])
x_train,y_train = np.array(X_train),np.array(y_train)
```

Error
'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: Remove the `.np`. `X_train.append`

Comment: Still the error remains

Comment: Than you have it in other places as well. Use `np` only when you want to access something directly from `numpy`.

Comment: I Have altered my code in my post can you recheck with the new error which is popping out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409498/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-append