# Can anyone knows this error in python tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy

This is my code:

```
image_array.append(image)
label_array.append(i)
    
image_array = np.array(image_array)
label_array = np.array(label_array, dtype="float")
```

This is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409498/attributeerror-numpy-ndarray-object-has-no-attribute-append)

Answer (score 2):

numpy.append expects two input atleast. see this example

```
import numpy as np

#define NumPy array
x = np.array([1, 4, 4, 6, 7, 12, 13, 16, 19, 22, 23])

#append the value '25' to end of NumPy array
x = np.append(x, 25)

#view updated array
x

array([ 1,  4,  4,  6,  7, 12, 13, 16, 19, 22, 23, 25])
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I can recall, you are writing the append in the wrong way (check here the example in the doc https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.append.html)

```
image_array = np.append(image_array, [image])
label_array = np.append(label_array, [i])
```

Arrays must have the same dimensions